# T-SQL: How can I split comma seperated values from a column to rows?

Tags: t-sql, transform, row

I have the following table (the number of the references is variable):

```
Id | FK_ID| Reference |
-----------------------
1    2100   GI2, GI32
2    2344   GI56
```

And I need the following result:

```
Id | FK_ID| Reference |
-----------------------
1    2100   GI2 
2    2100   GI32
3    2344   GI56
```

Is there any short way to transform the data like this using MS SQL Server 2005?

Thank you

EDIT: Direct link to the solution: 
http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#iter-list-of-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which SQL Server version are you using?

### Prior 2005

Use utility *Numbers* table as explained [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2000.html).
I've used it many times before with great success.

### 2005 and after

Read fellow developer *Mitch Wheat's* answer.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2005. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Please see:

- [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)